# If $g(x)=x^2+7)$ and $h(x)=x-5$, find $k$ if $g(h(x-k))$ is even.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> If $g(x)=x^2+7$ and $h(x)=x-5$, find $k$ if $g(h(x-k))$ is even.

I just got $0=0$; what did I do wrong?

$$g(x-k-5)=g(-x+k+5)$$
$$u=(x-k-5)$$
$$g(u^2+7)=g((-u)^2+7)$$
$$0=0$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be $$(x-5-k)^2+7=(-x-5-k)^2+7,$$
which gives $k=-5$.

Comment: Oh, what a simple mistake; I just happened to look back at this answer after the edit after I solved it and I got it, thanks!

Comment: @suomynonA You are welcome!